# Find distance from current location using gps coordinates

Tags: php, html, gps

I am trying to find out the distance of specific gps points from my current location. So i have an HTML file that calculates and displays the current location. And the coordinates are then sent to the server via a GET message. The php file in server has a function to calcuate distance. However, there is no `echo` displayed from the php file. Here is my implementation:

**HTML FILE**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var lat;
var lng;
        function clicked(){

        if(navigator.geolocation){
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success,error);
        }

        else{
            document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = "Not supported";
        }

        function success(position){
                lat = position.coords.latitude;
                lng = position.coords.longitude;
                document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = "lat :"+lat+"<br>long :"+lng;
                }

        function error(err){
                document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = "Error Code: "+error.code;
                if(err.code == 1){
                    document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = "Access denied";
                    }
                if(err.code == 2){
                    document.getElementById("hello").innerHTML = "Position unavailable";
                }
        }

        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){ 
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }else{ 
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
                if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
                    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
            }
            xmlhttp.open("GET","queryRestaurantsList.php?lat="+lat+"&lng="+lng,true);
            xmlhttp.send(); 
        }
</script>   
</head>
<body>

<div onclick="clicked()">Click Me!</div>
<div id="hello"></div>
<div id="list"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**PHP FILE**

```
<?
mysql_connect($host,$username,$password);
mysql_select_db($database) or die( "Unable to select database");

echo "HEllo WOrld!";


function distance($lat1,$lng1,$lat2,$lng2,$unit){

    $theta = $lng1 - $lng2;
    $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
    $dist = acos($dist);
    $dist = rad2deg($dist);
    $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
    $unit = strtoupper($unit);

    if ($unit == "M") {
        return (($miles * 1.609344)/1000);
      } 
}

//Check if POST array is empty or not
$lat1 = $_GET['lat'];
$lng1 = $_GET['lng'];

echo $lat1;
echo $lng1;

$query = "SELECT RestaurantID,Latitude,Longitude FROM RGeoLocation"
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Unable to execute query");

$i = 0;
$answer = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        $lat2 = row['Latitude'];
        $lng2 = row['Longitude'];
        $id = row['RestaurantID'];

        $answer[$i] = distance($lat1,$lng1,$lat2,$lng2,"M")
        $i++;
    } 

echo $answer;
?>
```

Comment: Your php file doesn't start with <?php

Comment: that is a typo. It has been corrected

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember you'll need to xmlhttp.open with the 2nd parameter as false (this will cause the script to pause and wait for a response).  You'll then need to write xmlhttp.responseText into from java, xmlhttp.repsonseText should contain the output from the php script.

Answer (score 0):

So this isn't really a question about GPS distance calculation - it's more about Basic PHP fundamentals.

In your PHP script $answer is an array. You cannot simply echo an array as you can a string or integer.

And maybe you should send the response JSON encoded:

```
echo json_encode($answer);
```